# How to obtain debug_token info using Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to verify and in the same time get some metadata on a specific access token through server side app - written in python.

The access token was generated using the JS Web SDK (on a static page with an ajax call back to my python server side)

When I get the json response on the server it lacks some key fields:

```
{
  "data": {
    "app_id": some_app_id_deleted,
    "application": some string app name deleted
    "is_valid": true,
    "scopes": [
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see the scopes field is empty and no other fields such as user_id and expiration_at that are described in the documentation [debug_token Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/debug_token)

I'm also testing it using the Graph API Explorer and getting the same missing results [Debug Token from the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=debug_token)

The really wierd thing is when I'm the [Debug Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken) I'm getting all of the fields in a correct way.

I guess the problem is with the input_token that I'm passing to the debug_token API call - I'm using [Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/) to find my app access token, and it looks like it's the right one. Is there another option for an input_token?

My question is: How can I get the same results I'm getting from the debug access token tool when I use the debug token API - as stated in the formal Facebook documentation.

What could be the input_token used by the [Debug Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken) when issuing the request?
Have anyone suffered from something similar?

**UPDATE:** This was a bug in my code, I've switched the parameters between 'input_token' and 'access_token' when formatting my url, which created this weird behavior.

```
    url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/debug_token?' \
    'input_token=%s&access_token=%s' % (app_token_str, token)
```

Comment: Input token is the token you want to debug. App access tokens don’t have a scope - so if you debugged your app token, then it is only natural that you don’t get a scope returned. (And in the debug tool you likely debugged a _different_ token. The field gets pre-filled automatically with a user access token for one of your apps; you need to copy&paste the right one.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, that gave us a hint as to what we were doing wrong. Apparently we were mixing the `input_token` parameter with the `access_token` which the debug_token API then validated and returned a different response from what we were expecting because we were simply validating the wrong token.